# ModelManager used in ForeignKey relations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-managers

I'm using Django 1.9 on my site and I need an effective way of completely ignore the inactive users, so I don't send them any notifications, emails, etc.

I've tried using a custom Model Manager that only returns the active ones, like this:

```
class ActiveAccountsManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ActiveAccountsManager, self).get_queryset().filter(user__is_active=True)


class Account(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Account')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Accounts')

    objects = ActiveAccountsManager()
    all_accounts = models.Manager()  # Enabling the obtention of all the users, instead of only the active ones
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=ACCOUNT_TYPES, default=-1)
```

And, while it works exactly as I want when I directly try to query Account objects, it doesn't when they are referenced through an object that has a ForeignKey relation with it. For example, if I had a Comment model like the following one:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Account)
```

I'd like that, when I query for Comment objects, the ones whose author is a inactive user (i.e. an user that the default Manager of the Account model won't return) aren't returned either, instead of the current behavior that returns the comment but says that the account related to it does not exist

Is there any way of achieving this without specifically defining a custom ModelManager on the Comment class? Because the thing is that I want to achieve this in a lot of classes related to the Account one and I can't think of a way of doing it without being extremely repetitive.

Please, don't hesitate to ask if any part of my question isn't clear enough or if I need to provide more details about my code. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It should already work in your case, as the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#default-managers) say:

> Default managers
>
> If you use custom Manager objects, take note that the first Manager
>   Django encounters (in the order in which they’re defined in the model)
>   has a special status. Django interprets the first Manager defined in a
>   class as the “default” Manager, and several parts of Django (including
>   dumpdata) will use that Manager exclusively for that model. As a
>   result, it’s a good idea to be careful in your choice of default
>   manager in order to avoid a situation where overriding get_queryset()
>   results in an inability to retrieve objects you’d like to work with.

Since the ActiveAccountsManager declaration comes first in your model, it should be already marked as the "default" one.

If you were to update to Django >= 1.10, you can set up explicitly the default manager for your model (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#default-manager-name).